# Using specific axes in ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm writing a class that is handling recorded intensity frames. These are stored in the class attribute `self.frames`.

I want to write an `ipywidget` with an `SelectionSlider` which selects what frame is plotted with matplotlib imshow. So I have my class instance,

```
measurement = Frames(file_path)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes()

measurement.plot_all_frames(ax=ax)
```

my function `plot_all_frames` looks like this

```
def plot_all_frames(self, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.axes()
    interact(lambda time: self.plot_frame_at_time(ax=ax, time=time, **kwargs), 
        time=widgets.SelectionSlider(
                options=self.time,
                value=self.time[0],
                description='Time:',
                disabled=False,
                continuous_update=False,
                orientation='horizontal',
                readout=True
            ))
```

When I run my code nothing is shown in the created figure. The reason I want to do it this way is to have control of the figure size and being able to set axes properties later. Also want to have it as a class method to reduce the amount of code shown in the notebook. Anyone knows how to fix this?